# Debuging .xll in Visual Studio kills attached Excel session

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

hopefully someone had the similar issue and will be able to help...
Visual Studio 2010

I have an xll file that is created using excel-DNA and C#. I'm able to attach it to excel spreadsheet with my xll loaded in and hit the break point in visual studio 2010 project when I use the method in the excel sheet. I also can see all passed in arguments with all the correct values. But as soon as I click step into to start debugging the code it crushes my excel. I also tried simply put second break point and execute code to go forward but it also crush excel. Have no idea what to try. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I suggest you start with a new Class Library project, install the 'Excel-DNA' package from NuGet, then check the debugging. That would give you a baseline expectation, and you can figure out whether your project or environment is special.

Comment: Thanks Govert, I tried that. Created a very simple method, which is giving the right value if I use it without debugging. But as soon as I attach to excel, hit debugging point in the code and try to step in excel closing without any messages (looks like excel process just being killed instantly). I think it some kind of setting on my machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by a Microsoft tool called the "Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit" (EMET). By default, it prevents debugging of Excel. You can check the Event Log for events that say something like: "EMET detected EAF mitigation and will close the application: EXCEL.EXE".

There is an EMET GUI tool that allows you to change the settings for Excel.

If not EMET, the problem might be caused by some similar security utility on that  computer.

Comment: Govert thanks a lot, you were absolutely right, it is EMET.